# Jade unordered list in unordered list

Tags: javascript, pug

I want to make an unordered list which contains an unordered list for each row.
I tried the code below but it just shows a combined unordered list of subjects and contents like

- SUBJECT1
- SUBJECT2
- content1
- content2

How can I show the content list inside the each subject list like

- SUBJECT1

  - content1
  - content2
- SUBJECT2

  - content1
  - content2

```
ul(class="subject_list")
  each subject in subjects
    li= subject
      ul(class="content_list")
        each content in contents
          li= content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the data of this type

```
{"subjects": {
 "subject1": ["content1", "content2"],
 "subject2": ["content1", "content2"]
}}
```

The equivalent jade/pug syntax would be

```
ul(class="subject_list")
  each subject, key in subjects
    li #{key}
    ul(class="content_list")
      each content in subject
        li #{content}
```